# How to implement computation of a certain covariance matrix?

Tags: covariance-matrix

The screenshot below from the paper "[Short-Term Variations and Long-Term Dynamics in Commodity Prices](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/epdf/10.1287/mnsc.46.7.893.12034)" by Schwartz and Smith (2000) shows the formula for the covariance matrix $V_n$ based on an initial matrix of brownian motion variances and correlation.

[image]

How is the computation of the $V_n$  supposed to be implemented? What would be the steps in its computation?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Including your work (attempt) would be helpful.